# Tomcat servlet not running - error 404

Tags: tomcat, servlets, web-applications, tomcat5

I have an application that is distributed with tomcat, I wanted to simply take the webapp from the webapps folder and put it into the webapps folder of a tomcat server, however when I do this and restart it etc whenever a servlet is referenced (such as /controller) it returns a 404 as if the servlets or the mapping aren't working. I'd provide more information but I am so at a loss I don't even know where to start debugging this (very new to tomcat) can someone point me in the right direction? Why would it work locally but not on this server.

Here is my web.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
<display-name>
BeergameProject</display-name>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>
    PlayerController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>PlayerController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    beergame.controller.PlayerController</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet>
    <description>
    </description>
    <display-name>
    AdminController</display-name>
    <servlet-name>AdminController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>
    beergame.controller.AdminController</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>PlayerController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/PlayerController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>AdminController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/AdminController</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.htm</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>default.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Comment: Can you share your web.xml file?

Comment: how to send a request to server? Like localhost:8080/beergame/controller ?

Answer (score 0):

in the web.xml you have /PlayerController and /AdminController in the serlet mapping.

So you should call

`localhost:8080/beergame/PlayerController` or `localhost:8080/beergame/AdminController`

Where beergame is the name of the folder which you have copied you